# Filtrar Textos diferentes em posições diversas no R

Tags: r

Boa tarde. Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
NOME  <- c("MARIA 1001", "MARIA 1002A", "JOSE 1003B", "PEDRO 1003", "CARLOS 1019J", “ANTONIO 50”, “MARIA 80”)
VALOR <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70)
dados <- data.frame(NOME, VALOR)
```

Necessito filtrar as linhas que estão entre 1001 a 1019, independente de sua posição (início, meio ou final do texto).
O meu resultado esperado é que exclua apenas as linhas `"ANTONIO 50"` e `"MARIA 80"`. Gostaria de ajuda como proceder para fazer este filtro. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  filter(str_extract(NOME, "\\d{1,}") %in% 1001:1019)
```

A função `str_extract` extrai um padrão de uma string usando regex. No caso, o padrão é: `\\d{1,}`, isto é, pelo menos 1 número inteiro.

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte. Primeiro usamos o `gsub` para obter só os números em `dados$NOME`. Depois, filtramos com um índice lógico.

```
num <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", dados$NOME))
dados2 <- dados[1001 <= num & num <= 1019, ]
rm(num)    # já não é preciso

dados2 
#          NOME VALOR
#1   MARIA 1001    10
#2  MARIA 1002A    20
#3   JOSE 1003B    30
#4   PEDRO 1003    40
#5 CARLOS 1019J    50
```